# Notepad++ SourceCookifier plugin very slow on large C++ headers

Tags: c++, notepad++

I like to browse through my C++ projects in Notepad++. I use the SourceCookifier Plugin in order to easily jump in between definitions on large files. However, if I load a large C++ header file (around 30.000 lines), with a lot of `#define` and `typedef` declarations inside, it seems to hang and takes a long of time to load.

Does anyone know if there is any option one can set to make it faster or can this plugin generally not load so many definitions?

Comment: In general parsing C++ is relatively slow. Most IDEs build up a database, either per file or per project, with to cache the parsed files so subsequent and incremental changes are quicker. So unless you can turn something like that on, I doubt there's much you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accelerate everything by throwing your project folder into the SourceCookifier panel while (and this is the important but badly documented part) **pressing a modifier key (shift, ctrl or alt)**.

> .. for importing INCLUDE files. But you have to additionally either
>   press the CTRL, SHIFT or ALT key while dropping a file or folder into
>   the treeview.

Or even smarter... separately only add your large define/typedef sources like described. It will result in a performance boost, since their **symbols won't be listed in the tree view anymore**, but SourceCookifier will still navigate you there, when hitting "Go To Definition" on one of their symbols somewhere else in the project.

I also sometimes use to add header files with several thousand defines to a SourceCookifier session. Without pressing ctrl-key it takes up to 5 mins per file, but with pressing ctrl-key it only takes 1 second!

EDIT/

Adding source files **without** pressing ctrl-key:

- "Go To Definition" functionality? Yes.
- Symbols shown in tree view as subnodes of source file node? Yes.
- ==> **Not** recommended for **laaaarge** source files.

Adding source files **with** pressing ctrl-key:

- "Go To Definition" functionality? Yes.
- Symbols shown in tree view as subnodes of source file node? **NO.**
- ==> **Recommended** for **laaaarge** source files.

Comment: If I use CTRL or SHIFT, I see the `.hpp` file on the right hand side under the `INCLUDES` folder, but without any symbols. So in order to see the symbols underneath it, I must important in the normal, long way, right?

Comment: So basically, if I want to see my symbols, I need to add the source files to the tree view. They will be indexed and shown in the pane but the header file symbols will be kept only in memory and not shown in the pane.